# Storing Python function parameters as a variable to call later

Tags: python, django, parameters

I have a function where, based on different case, I'm changing the parameters sent to a function whose result I'm returning.  I would like to just decide parameters in the middle of the method, and only have one return call at the bottom of my function. Please be aware this is not what my code looks like, it's just an example.  I'm using Django, if that's relevant.

```
if x:
    return func(param1, param2, param3)
elif y:
    return func(param4, param5, param6)
elif z:
    return func(param7, param8, param9)
```

I would like this to read

```
if x:
    parameters = (param1, param2, param3)
elif y:
    parameters = (param4, param5, param6)
elif z:
    parameters = (param7, param8, param9)
return func(parameters)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `*` to [unpack the parameter tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
func(*parameters)
```

**Demo:**

```
def func(x,y,z):
     print x,y,z
>>> params = (1,2,3)
>>> func(*params)
1 2 3
>>> params = (4,5,6)
>>> func(*params)
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do

`return func(*parameters)`

It unpacks the parameters and passes it to the `func`. Read the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) entry on this.

For example -

```
>>> def test(a, b, c):
        print a, b, c


>>> testList = [2, 3, 4]
>>> test(*testList)
2 3 4
```

Your code would now read -

```
if x:
    parameters = (param1, param2, param3)
elif y:
    parameters = (param4, param5, param6)
elif z:
    parameters = (param7, param8, param9)
return func(*parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a pythonic approach to this that's kind of pretty:

```
paramDictionary = { x : (param 1, param 2, param 3), y : (...), z:(...) }
return func( *paramDictionary[ indicator ] )
```

This tends to be neater code in python. You're still using the * to unpack your variables, but you don't need rambling lines of if statements!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do

```
return func(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2])
```

?